# how to expand to full path file name according to path variable in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

As I thought, the variable expand command:

```
%~dp$PATH:I
```

is used for iterating through the paths in `%path%` variable and find the first occurrence in which contains the file name specified by the variable `%I`,then expand the `%I` to the full path filename.
And it is exactly what I want to do in my `.bat` file, so I tried this command and failed.

Am I wrong about what this command means? Or just I am doing it wrong?

Comment: "Am I wrong about what this command means?" Yes. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `%~$PATH:I` works _in certain sense_ analogous to `where` command. For instance, compare commands `for %I in (help) do @echo %I: %~$PATH:I` and `for %I in (help) do @where %I`. Read `where /?` and `call /?` for explanation.